# What's the use case of p:collector vs custom wrapper class?

Tags: collections, primefaces

I didn't know about `p:collector`. I created this custom abstract class:

```java
abstract public class Wrapper<T> {
    protected Integer number;
    protected List<T> list;
    protected Class<T> klass;
    
    public Wrapper() {
        this.setList(new ArrayList<T>());
    }
    
    public void setListNumber(Integer number) {
        Class<T> klass = this.getKlass();
        List<T> list = this.getList();
        ListUtil.setSize((ArrayList<T>) list, number, klass);
    }
    
    public void add() {
        List<T> list = this.getList();
        Class<T> klass = this.getKlass();
        try {
            list.add(klass.newInstance());
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new InstantiationUncheckedException(e);
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalAccessUncheckedException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public void remove(int i) {
        List<T> list = this.getList();
        list.remove(i);
    }
    
    
    
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    
    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    
    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public Class<T> getKlass() {
        return klass;
    }

    public void setKlass(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }
}
```

and I usually use it this way:

```java
public class Things extends Wrapper<Thing> {
    public Things() {
        super();
        this.setKlass(Thing.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Things [number=" + number + ", list=" + list + "]";
    }
}
```

and in the view, for example:

```html
<ui:repeat varStatus="status" var="thing" value="#{bean.things.list}">
```

and

```html
<p:commandButton 
    value="Add"
    action="#{bean.things.add()}"
    immediate="true"
/>

<p:commandButton 
    value="❌"
    action="#{bean.licenze.remove(status.index)}"
    immediate="true"
/>
```

`p:collector` collector could do this better/with less code?

Comment: Thank you.  Unluckily, I can't find docs of 10, I read the docs of 8. If you answer me I accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p:collector` was [removed in PrimeFaces 11](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/11_0_0) after being [deprecated in 10](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0), so better not use it if you ever want to upgrade.